# Empty fields. Wordpress plugin CPT-onomies

Tags: php, wordpress

On the admin page I have an empty field.

[image]

In file `plugins/cpt-onomies/admin.php` function

```
wp_terms_checklist( $post->ID, array( ‘taxonomy’ => $taxonomy, ‘popular_cats’ => $popular_ids, ‘walker’ => new CPTonomy_Walker_Terms_Checklist() ) );
```

is returning only

```
<li id=”sity-“><label class=”selectit”><input value=”” type=”checkbox” name=”_custom_post_type_onomies_relationship[sity][]” id=”in-sity-“> </label>“.
```

If change `$taxonomy` from "sity" to "category" function return posts correctly.

Custom post types available by link `edit.php?post_type=sity`

Comment: Are you sure you have "sity" taxonomy? Because for now looks like "sity" it's post type. Another way please give more information.

Comment: on link http://basis-spb.ru/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=sity  i have this....  [link](http://prntscr.com/czk198)

Comment: if i create new taxonomy by Simple Taxonomy - http://prntscr.com/czk2mk